# Implementing "full convolution" to find gradient w.r.t the convolution layer inputs

Tags: machine-learning, python, convolution, backpropagation, numpy

I've been trying to implement "full convolution" w.r.t to convolution layer inputs. According to [this](https://medium.com/@pavisj/convolutions-and-backpropagations-46026a8f5d2c) article, it looks like this:

[image]

So, I wrote this function:

```
def full_convolve(filters, gradient):
    filters = np.ones((5,5))
    gradient = np.ones((8,8))
    result = list()
    output_shape = 12
    filter_r = filters.shape[0] - 1
    filter_c = filters.shape[1] - 1
    gradient_r = gradient.shape[0] - 1
    gradient_c = gradient.shape[1] - 1

    for i in range(0,output_shape):
        if (i <= filter_r):
            row_slice = (0, i + 1)
            filter_row_slice = ( 0 , i + 1)
        elif ( i > filter_r and i <= gradient_r):
            row_slice = (i - filter_r, i + 1)
            filter_row_slice = (0, i + 1)
        else: 
            rest = ((output_shape - 1) -  i )
            row_slice = (gradient_r  - rest, i + 1 )
            filter_row_slice = (0 ,rest + 1)
        for b in range(0,output_shape):
            if (b <= filter_c):
                col_slice = (0, b + 1)
                filter_col_slice = (0, b+1)
            elif (b > filter_c and b <= gradient_c):
                col_slice = (b - filter_c, b + 1)
                filter_col_slice = (0,b+1)
            else:
                rest = (output_shape - 1 ) - b 
                col_slice = (gradient_r - rest , b + 1)
                filter_col_slice = (0, rest + 1)
            r = np.sum(gradient[row_slice[0] : row_slice[1], col_slice[0] : col_slice[1]] * filters[filter_row_slice[0]: filter_row_slice[1], filter_col_slice[0]: filter_col_slice[1]])
            result.append(r)
    result = np.asarray(result).reshape(12,12)
```

I tested this with ones and the output seems correct (if I get "full convolution" right):

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.]
 [ 2.  4.  6.  8. 10. 10. 10. 10.  8.  6.  4.  2.]
 [ 3.  6.  9. 12. 15. 15. 15. 15. 12.  9.  6.  3.]
 [ 4.  8. 12. 16. 20. 20. 20. 20. 16. 12.  8.  4.]
 [ 5. 10. 15. 20. 25. 25. 25. 25. 20. 15. 10.  5.]
 [ 5. 10. 15. 20. 25. 25. 25. 25. 20. 15. 10.  5.]
 [ 5. 10. 15. 20. 25. 25. 25. 25. 20. 15. 10.  5.]
 [ 5. 10. 15. 20. 25. 25. 25. 25. 20. 15. 10.  5.]
 [ 4.  8. 12. 16. 20. 20. 20. 20. 16. 12.  8.  4.]
 [ 3.  6.  9. 12. 15. 15. 15. 15. 12.  9.  6.  3.]
 [ 2.  4.  6.  8. 10. 10. 10. 10.  8.  6.  4.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.]]
```

However, I don't like all these manual checks and if/else statements. I feel there is a better way to implement this in NumPy (perhaps, using some zero paddings or something like this). Can anyone suggest a better approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

j5 = np.ones((5,5))
j8 = np.ones((8,8))

c58 = signal.convolve2d(j5, j8, boundary='fill')  # by default filled with 0, which is correct for your case
```

Results in:

```
print(c58)
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.]
 [ 2.  4.  6.  8. 10. 10. 10. 10.  8.  6.  4.  2.]
 [ 3.  6.  9. 12. 15. 15. 15. 15. 12.  9.  6.  3.]
 [ 4.  8. 12. 16. 20. 20. 20. 20. 16. 12.  8.  4.]
 [ 5. 10. 15. 20. 25. 25. 25. 25. 20. 15. 10.  5.]
 [ 5. 10. 15. 20. 25. 25. 25. 25. 20. 15. 10.  5.]
 [ 5. 10. 15. 20. 25. 25. 25. 25. 20. 15. 10.  5.]
 [ 5. 10. 15. 20. 25. 25. 25. 25. 20. 15. 10.  5.]
 [ 4.  8. 12. 16. 20. 20. 20. 20. 16. 12.  8.  4.]
 [ 3.  6.  9. 12. 15. 15. 15. 15. 12.  9.  6.  3.]
 [ 2.  4.  6.  8. 10. 10. 10. 10.  8.  6.  4.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.  4.  3.  2.  1.]]
```

Reference to see other options when you'd need them:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html

Comment: Thanks, but this is one-liner. It would be more interesting to see how such function could be actually implemented. I checked the source but did not find the procedure.

Comment: @Jim, the documentation is like: "pad input arrays with fillvalue. (default)". You pad the input arrays with (filterlength-1) with zero, in two dimensions, on all 4 sides. This makes your row slice ignore terms by multiplications with zero instead of an if then else. Alternatively you can use min/max to calculate starts and ends but those are hidden if/then/elses

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense